# The First Option in the Drop Down gets Fixed all though I set it to display None using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The First Option in the Drop Down gets Fixed all though I set it to display None using javascript

I'm trying to populate all the values of the dropdown and use classes to differentiate it when a user chooses men he should get only class=b1 similarly for all  it works but the first option remains selected always where am i missing the trick !! help me buddies

I am using HTML CSS and Javascript in Here nothing other than that ..

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function get(id) 
    { 
    if(id==1)
    {
    var divsb1 = document.getElementsByClassName('b1');
    for(var i=0; i<divsb1.length; i++) { 
    divsb1[i].style.display='block'
    }

    var divsb2 = document.getElementsByClassName('b2');
    for(var i=0; i<divsb2.length; i++) { 
    divsb2[i].style.display='none'
    }

    var divsb3 = document.getElementsByClassName('b3');
    for(var i=0; i<divsb3.length; i++) { 
    divsb3[i].style.display='none'
    }   
    }
    else if(id==2)
    {


        var divsb2 = document.getElementsByClassName('b1');
        for(var i=0; i<divsb2.length; i++) { 
        divsb2[i].style.display='none';
        }
    var divsb1 = document.getElementsByClassName('b2');
    for(var i=0; i<divsb1.length; i++) { 
    divsb1[i].style.display='block'
    }



    var divsb3 = document.getElementsByClassName('b3');
    for(var i=0; i<divsb3.length; i++) { 
    divsb3[i].style.display='none';
    }   

    }
    else if(id==3)
    {
        var divsb1 = document.getElementsByClassName('b3');
    for(var i=0; i<divsb1.length; i++) { 
    divsb1[i].style.display='block'
    }

    var divsb2 = document.getElementsByClassName('b2');
    for(var i=0; i<divsb2.length; i++) { 
    divsb2[i].style.display='none'
    }

    var divsb3 = document.getElementsByClassName('b1');
    for(var i=0; i<divsb3.length; i++) { 
    divsb3[i].style.display='none'
    }   

    }
    } //end of function
    </script>

    </head>


    <body>

    <label  class="alt-label">
    <input type="radio" id="adserve" value="1" name="server_for" onclick="get(1)" />Men
    </label>
    <label class="alt-label">
    <input type="radio" id="adserve" value="2" name="server_for" onclick="get(2)" />Women
    </label>
    <label class="alt-label">
    <input type="radio" id="adserve" value="3" name="server_for" onclick="get(3)" />Kids
    </label>

    <select name="brands" id="brands"> 
    <option class="b1" value="100">T-Shirts</option>
    <option class="b1" value="12">Accessories & Combo Sets</option>
    <option class="b2" value="23">Lingerie & Sleepwear</option>
    <option class="b2" value="24">Accessories</option>
    <option class="b3" value="27">Boys Wear</option>
    <option class="b3" value="28">Girls Wear</option>
    </select>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why it is tagged with `jQuery`?

Comment: A better design might be dynamically populate the drop downbased on gender selection?

Comment: hey buddy dynamically populating takes some time(as you know we require to fire an event through ajax and get back the response), so i wanted to try and do it in javascript or jquery as i can add a class for option tag the result of the code was as expected but the first option element seems to be fixed

Comment: Friends i have tagged it as jquery also because i'm open to accept jquery soln also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to hide select option using CSS.What you can do is to disable them based on checkbox selection.

to enable:

```
   divsb1[i].disabled =false;
```

to disable:

```
   divsb1[i].disabled =true;
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xMLpS/)**